# can't insert 2 calendar elements in the same page with twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap v2.1.1, and I can't insert two datepicker objects on the same page (`<input type="text" class="span8" id="dp1" />`). The first object works but not the second one....
This has happened before with the calendar object too...

Any idea on how can I solve this?

Comment: First of all, the date picker is not a supported feature of Twitter Bootstrap, but a third-party plugin. Which one are you using ? Please paste the activation code. Hint: an `id=""` must be unique.

Comment: it was the id thing, noob's mistake...:/. Thanks all ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have two distinct `id=""` s. That way the calendar UI will know which field to attach itself to